# Azure IP Range white list using pipeline for Access Restriction on Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, vnet

We are having Azure function app which is deployed using ARM Template, It also include the [Access Restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) which is applied while provision the Function app. We want to white list set of IP Range(Azure Data center IP Range) because of SaaS functionality dependency.

From the [following link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) we can get the IP Range in json format, Which is updated on weekly basis(Monday).  We need to automate the IP whitelist from this file, azure pipelines are being used.

Tried writing power shell script, the download page and actually download URL are different(URL changes periodically).

VNET, Security group can be used because of the [limitation of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#network-security-groups) Azure on Function App Inbound traffic.

Any standard way of handling the above mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to protect your functions in scenarios like this would be to place a gateway like [Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) in front of your functions.

The function will accept requests only from the APIM instance's IP and requests coming to APIM can be authorized by either

- [Subscription Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-create-subscriptions) (Can be in the header or as a query parameter)
- [Client Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients)
- [OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) (a [`validate-jwt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests) policy is required for validating the JWT passed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, We have implemented kind of same mechanism. 
We added apim under vnet(subnet1)  and on Function apps we allowed apim subnet using vnet integration.

We configured NSG with security tag to allow the required traffic on the apim vnet. It worked for us. 

Note : APIM vnet integration is only supported in developer plan (cheap and NO SLA provided) and Premium plan (2700$ per month). Other plans(basic, Standard) doesn't provide the VNET integraiton feature. Be careful while implementing the vnet on APIM with respect to cost.